# How to choose a certain edge in Geometry Node (Blender 3.4.0 alpha)

Tags: geometry, blender

two questions about Geometry Nodes.
To retopologize certain mesh, I'd like to subdivide a certain edge that both neighbors are triangle.

**Questions:**(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG3Us.png)

> 1.How to find the edge with Geometry Node?
> 2.Is there a general strategy to find a specific elements(index of vertex, edge, and face)?

**History:**
I want to retopo the shape(=A) of being after Convex Hull Node because this is messy.
To do so, I chose a way that is of shrinking a simple shape onto A.

Bounding Box > Subdivide > Set Position is the order of the Nodes, but large areas still remain.
To fit the shape more precisely, I am trying to subdivide  adittionaly only on the areas and then finally Set Position Node again to fit to the original messy A.

After I have tried some ideas (bellow), now I am trying to do a way of extruding the face, scaling the top selection to zero, merge the face and the set these new 'vertex' to the messy A.

And I find the **edge between the face** remain.
This is my question above. **How to fit these edges on to A?**

Ideas I have tried:
  
Separate the large areas>Subdivide>Join Geometry>Set Position makes holes.
  
Separate the large areas>Subdivide>Convex Hull>Boolean Mesh makes messy topology

The way of not subdividing the large area, such as scaling the bounding box up enough to disappear the large area, will result overstretch to other mesh, which looks more difficult to solve, so I prefer to solve large flatten area If I can.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzHKa.jpg)

I want to do retopology. I want to fit a new shape that has a clean topology onto the original messy shape.

Comment: For now, it seems easier to adjust the size and number of faces of the original BoundingBox than to split it into parts later.

Comment: It was easier to sort out the occurrence of a somewhat unusual face of the error with a few nodes. I resolved it. Thank you!

Comment: You may want to try https://blender.stackexchange.com/ for this type o question in the future.